# Use order inside include in sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

```
Discussion.findAll({
    where : {
        discussion_on : profileId,
        is_deleted : false ,
        is_reply : false
    },
    limit : 5,
    order : [['updated_at','DESC']],
    offset:5*(page-1),
    // order : [['updated_at','DESC']],

    include:[{
        model : Profile,
        as : 'CommentBy',
        attributes:staticData.USER_LAYOUT,
        include : [{
            model : TeamMember,
            as : "TeamSender",
            required : false,
            attributes : ['receiver', 'title'],
            where : sequelize.where(sequelize.col('receiver'),db.sequelize.col('discussion.comment_entity'))
        },{
            model : TeamMember,
            required : false,
            as : "TeamReceiver",
            attributes : ['sender', 'title'],
            where : sequelize.where(sequelize.col('CommentBy.TeamReceiver.sender'),db.sequelize.col('discussion.comment_entity'))
        }]
    },{
        model : Discussion,
        as : 'Replies',
        required : false ,
        order : [['Replies.created_at','ASC']],
        where : {
            is_deleted : false
        } ,
        include:[{
            model : Profile,
            as : "CommentBy",
            attributes:staticData.USER_LAYOUT,
            include : [{
                model : TeamMember,
                as : "TeamSender",
                required : false,
                attributes : ['receiver', 'title'],
                where : sequelize.where(sequelize.col('Replies.CommentBy.TeamSender.receiver'),db.sequelize.col('Replies.comment_entity'))
            },{
                model : TeamMember,
                required : false,
                as : "TeamReceiver",
                attributes : ['sender', 'title'],
                where : sequelize.where(sequelize.col('Replies.CommentBy.TeamReceiver.sender'),db.sequelize.col('Replies.comment_entity'))
            }]
        },{
            model:Profile,
            as : "CommentEntity",
            attributes:staticData.USER_LAYOUT
        }]
    },{
            model:Profile,
            as : "CommentEntity",
            attributes:staticData.USER_LAYOUT
    }]
})
```

Discussion is the object name.
Basically this query fetches all the comments with their replies attached to each comment .I want the replies to be sorted by date as well.

This is what i want to achieve inside Replies . But it does not work

order : [['created_at','ASC']],

Answer (score 2):

Try this, It will **helpful** for you.

```
Discussion.findAll({
limit: 5,
....
order: [
        ['updated_at', 'DESC']
        ['Replies','created_at', 'ASC'],
       
    ],
....
})
```

You have to **define like this**

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this way later, here's what works:

https://medium.com/fredwong-it/sequelize-sort-another-model-in-include-by-using-order-5b7d68dadbbf

You need to add the `order` to the top level `order` array, and mention the model that it's for. In the case of the above code it'd look like:

```
Discussion.findAll({
  ...
  order : [
    [{ model: Replies }, 'created_at', 'ASC'], 
    ['updated_at','DESC']
  ],
  ... 
})
```